# Is renouncing one's US citizenship approx. equally administratively complex as renouncing one's US lawful permanent resident status (green card)?

Tags: usa, citizenship, greencard, french-citizens, renouncing-citizenship

Is renouncing [one's US citizenship](https://www.usa.gov/renounce-lose-citizenship) approximately equally administratively complex as [renouncing one's US lawful permanent resident status](https://www.uscis.gov/i-407) (i.e., giving up one's green card)?

If that matters (e.g., for tax treaties), the US lawful permanent resident or US citizen is also a French citizen.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Is renouncing one's US citizenship approximately equally administratively complex as renouncing one's US lawful permanent resident status (i.e., giving up one's green card)?

Not at all.  You can relinquish permanent residence quite easily, even [by mail](https://www.uscis.gov/i-407), and there is no fee.  Renouncing citizenship requires [appearing before a consular officer](https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/legal/travel-legal-considerations/us-citizenship/Renunciation-US-Nationality-Abroad.html) and a hefty fee, [currently $2350](https://www.law.cornell.edu/cfr/text/22/22.1).